# Excel comments do not stay near cell

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet I am using like a database - I sort it a lot of different ways depending on what I need.  I have comments in some cells.  When I click "show comments" the comment is sometimes over a thousand rows below the cell it is connected to.  See screen shots:

I want to see my comment and click show comment - it's way down there:

[image: Where's my comment?]

I scroll and scroll almost 1000 rows down - there it is! The size has changed to barely visible and now I have to resize and drag it back up.

[image: There it is]

Now I've got it back up and re-sized.  Why is it doing this and what's a best practice to make it stop?  I searched for this answer, but didn't find anything similar to my issue.

[image: Moved back to where I left it when I made it.]

Comment: [This](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2252-excel-reset-comment-positions.html#a1) may be of interest

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - Woah, that's awesome. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: You might also be able to find help on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: I assume these comments were copied/pasted or created programmatically (as opposed to manually for each cell)?

Comment: Thanks so much cybernetic!  I was manually creating all these memos and then when I sorted the workbook they would be everywhere!

Answer (score 0):

I added to extendoffice's code shared by @cybernetic.nomad to also resize the comment boxes to be the size of the comment and not huge or tiny.  Then I added the

```
Application.screenupdating=False
```

command to the beginning because my sheet is quite large and so it was slow running the code.  Here's my final:

```
Sub ResetComments()
'move comments back to parent cell and autosize

Dim pComment As Comment

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each pComment In Application.ActiveSheet.Comments
   pComment.Shape.Top = pComment.Parent.Top + 5
   pComment.Shape.Left = pComment.Parent.Offset(0, 1).Left + 5
   pComment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
Next
End Sub
```

Thank you everyone!  I was looking for a way to prevent moving the comments, but this fixes it easily!